# How does Genshin Impact integrate with the PSN and what can PS players do to increase privacy?

Tags: psn, genshin-impact

This is a question that came to mind while chatting in one of the network chatrooms about a recent event in the game that will force players to play random co-op to be able to participate Apparently this caused a lot of mixed felling from the player base, with angry posts on various topics (security/hacking, not liking co-op etc - see for example [here](https://www.hoyolab.com/genshin/article/362368) ).

During the exchange, we mentioned PS players as a comparison to PC ones.
Genshin works kinda different on PS, since the game is tied to the PSN account and not to a specific Mihoyo account like it does on PC.

For that reason, I was wondering about HOW exactly the game integrates with the PSN. More specifically:

- The PSN network has a series of setting for privacy like invisible mode and so on. Does this affect the ability of other players to see you online in the Genshin Impact co-op list?
- Is the in-game friend list tied to the PSN friend list? I know some game do that (Mediamolecule's Dream being a great offender for example). Adding a friend in Genshin Impact should just required registering their UID - assuming that means adding the player as a friend in the PSN too, how that integrate with the PSN "block friend requests" setting? Can the game bypass that?
- The game co-op menu displays PSN users names along with their in-game name. Can that be stopped, either in the game or by tweaking the PSN setting?

Basically I want to know what info about the player the game makes available to other players, how easy is for strangers to randomly add you as a friend and what can be done either in game or in the PSN settings to limit what others can do/see. Game design theory has nothing to do with this, despite what some seem to think.